# Erro ao tentar compactar as pastas de uma unidade - UnAuthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, segurança, permissões

Eu preciso compactar todas as pastas do meu E:\ 
Mas quando eu tento com esse código, eu recebo essa exceção de acesso.
Eu sou novo em programação e estou tentando aprender como fazer as coisas direitinho.
Eu estou usando o dotnetzip para compactar os diretórios dentro de E:\
Algumas partes do código são copiadas, eu sei disso... mas foi porque todas as soluções que eu mesmo tentei não deram certo, então só tentei implementar coisas que pareceram funcionar pra outras pessoas

Eu já tentei algumas outras soluções para resolver o problema respondidas aqui na Stack mesmo. Como adicionar um manifesto ao projeto que usa o requeireAdministrator para executar o projeto, e inserir uma regra de controle de acesso AccessRule para modificar a segurança do E:\ uma coisa que eu percebo quando faço isso é que meu usuário tem suas permissões removidas dos sub-arquivos e diretórios do E:\ Mas sem essa regra de acesso, a mesma exceção continua existindo. Não sei se estou implementando ela errado...

Bom, obrigado pela atenção a quem ler até aqui!
Vou deixar aqui em baixo o que eu quero fazer com o programa e o catch do erro:

```
  try
    {

        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
        zip.AddDirectory(@"E:\");
        zip.Save(@"C:\Users\vitorbento\Desktop\backup.zip");

        Console.WriteLine("Compactação concluída");
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        FileAttributes attr = (new FileInfo(DirectPath)).Attributes;
        Console.Write("UnAuthorizedAccessException: Unable to access file. ");
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) > 0)
        Console.Write("The file is read-only.");
    }
```

Comment: Você já tentou executar o aplicativo como administrador? (para debugar, o visual studio deve ser aberto com administrador também)

Comment: Já tentei abrir o Visual Studio como administrador, assim como abrir o arquivo gerado como administrador também.

Answer (score 0):

Tentou utilizar a classe estática ZipFile presente em System.IO.Compression ?

Poderias utilizar o método CreateFromDirectory dessa forma:

```
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"E:\", @"C:\Users\vitorbento\Desktop\backup.zip");
            Console.WriteLine("Compactação concluída");
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

Comment: De que forma isso iria ajudar com um erro de permissão na pasta?

Comment: Já tentei desenvolver o mesmo programa com o ZipFile, mas tive o mesmo problema com as permissões.